# Find the content between two HTML tags

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract only the number "4" in this HTML code using Python `beautifulsoup` what should I do?

```html
<ul class="left slider_pinfo">
    <li>
                <i class="ihome-bed"></i>
                       " 4"
                        <div class="meta-tooltip">bed</div>
                <span class="right listing-sp"></span>
                </li>
                                                <li>
                    <i class="ihome-arrows"></i>
                    "300meter"
                    <div class="meta-tooltip">meter</div>
                </li>
                                                <li>
                    <i class="ihome-building-age"></i>
                    "6years"
                    <div class="meta-tooltip">age</div>
                </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: You will need some code to do this. Try searching your issue first.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what else is in the full HTML, but using the HTML you have provided, you could first locate the `<i>` element using its class of `ihome-bed` and then navigate to the text element that follows. A standard Python `strip()` could then be used to remove newlines spaces and quote characters. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<ul class="left slider_pinfo">
    <li>
        <i class="ihome-bed"></i>
               " 4"
                <div class="meta-tooltip">bed</div>
        <span class="right listing-sp"></span>
        </li>
                                        <li>
            <i class="ihome-arrows"></i>
            "300meter"
            <div class="meta-tooltip">meter</div>
        </li>
                                        <li>
            <i class="ihome-building-age"></i>
            "6years"
            <div class="meta-tooltip">age</div>
        </li>
                </ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
number = soup.find('i', class_='ihome-bed').next_element.strip('\n" ')

print(number)
```

Would display:

```
4
```